# How to uninstall an application installed in the user profile without administrator?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I deal with a Windows 10 desktop (Windows 10 Enterprise 2015 LTSB) which is intentionally configured by the administrator to allow users to run software, but to do not allow users to install software system-wide without the administrator. Many applications are designed to successfully install in such environment, such as Chrome, Firefox, Telegram, Viber, WhatsApp etc. They install to the user profile and show properly in the start menu, file association etc. But if I go to Settings > System > Applications (or something similar in my language), all the options to uninstall the applications are greyed out. How to remove them properly without administrator, including the applications, associated files, configuration, start menu items etc?

Comment: You don’t;  Your Administrator doesn’t want you to uninstall it.  The Administrator must make the required configuration changes to do what you want

Comment: @Ramhound You mean that the end user can install software,  but cannot uninstall it because of how the administrator configured the system?

Comment: If you are unable to uninstall the software, from with the Control Panel, that is exactly what I am saying.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you! Your comment is the answer. As I explained in my question, I was looking in Windows Settings, where uninstalling is greyed out. But uninstalling with the Control Panel works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ramhound indicated in the comment, if you are allowed to uninstall software, the option should be available in the Control Panel.

So, if the option to uninstall applications is grayed out in `Settings > System > Apps & features` or `Settings > Apps & features` (depending on your Windows 10 flavor), try the Control Panel instead. When in `Settings > System > Apps & features`, there should be a link at the right or at the bottom saying `Related settings > Programs and Features`, which gets you directly to the relevant section of the Control Panel. If the link is absent, hit the Windows `Start` button, type `control panel` (`панель керування` in Ukrainian) to search for it, and hit enter to open it. Then click `Uninstall a program` to get to the section.